# How can I say a set has measure $1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $(\Omega,\mathscr{E},\mathbb{P})$ is a measure space such that $\mathbb{P}(\Omega)=1$.

Suppose $A_i \in \mathscr{E}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Suppose $\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{1 \leq i \leq n} A_i)=1$.

Can I conclude that there exists $1 \leq i \leq n$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A_i)=1$? If not, how can I found a counterexample?

I know the inclusion-exclusion principle, but I do not know if we can use it here and how.

In addition, are there conditions (i.e.  $(\Omega,\mathscr{E},\mathbb{P})$ has not atoms) such that the statement holds?

Comment: If you know that $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset \dots$ then it is true.  But otherwise it can fail even for the simplest measure spaces, simply by taking the $A_i$ to be disjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $\mu$ the Lesbegue measure on $[0,1]$ and choose some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, consider
$$A_k = \left[\frac{k-1}{n}, \frac{k}{n}\right], \text{ for } 1 \leq k \leq n-1.$$

Then $\mu(A_k) = \frac{1}{n}$, for all $k \in \{1, \dots, n-1\}$, but $\displaystyle\cup_{k=1}^{n-1} A_k = [0,1]$, so that $\mu(\cup_{k=1}^{n-1} A_k) = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot conclude that: consider $A_1 = [0,\frac12]. A_2 = [\frac12,1]$ on $[0,1]$ with the Borel sets and Lebesgue measure. For intersection it would be true of course.

Answer (score 1):

No. There seems to be no inclusion hypothesis in your statement.

Consider $\Omega=[0,1]$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets and the the usual probability $dx$. Then you can have
$$A_j = \left(\frac{j-1}{n},\frac{j}{n}\right)\,.$$
Clearly the union has probability one but they are all disjoint and with probability $1/n$.